# Listbox won't display updated database info once program is published

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I am a beginner to programming and I am trying to make a program that tracks my jogging data in WPF.  I set up a listbox that has databinding with my compact sql database where my info gets logged to.  While I am in visual studio it works as it should, but when I publish the program, the listbox will no longer display the proper info from the database.  It starts fresh all over again each time I start a new session of the program.  I know that the info is in the database because I have charts that will properly show all the latest logged data.  The listbox, however, will only show data logged during that current session.  When I close down the program and reopen, the data from my previous session is not displayed in the listbox anymore.

My code looks like this:

```
    runDataDataSet1 ds;
    runDataDataSet1TableAdapters.runDataTableTableAdapter dt;
    weightDataSet wds;
    weightDataSetTableAdapters.weightTableTableAdapter wdt;


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ds = ((runDataDataSet1)(this.FindResource("runDataDataSet1")));
        dt = new runDataDataSet1TableAdapters.runDataTableTableAdapter();
        dt.Fill(ds.runDataTable);
        CollectionViewSource cvs = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("runDataTableViewSource")));
        cvs.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

        wds = ((weightDataSet)(this.FindResource("weightDataSet")));
        wdt = new weightDataSetTableAdapters.weightTableTableAdapter();
        wdt.Fill(wds.weightTable);
        CollectionViewSource wcvs = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("weightTableViewSource")));
        wcvs.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

To submit the data I have this code for when the submit button is pushed:

```
double pace = runData.runPace(runData.milesRun, runData.timeRun);
        double pace2 = Math.Round(pace, 1);
        double milesDuration = Math.Round((runData.mileDuration(runData.milesRun, runData.timeRun)), 1);
        paceTextBox.Text = ((milesDuration) + " min mile");
        //UPDATE DATABASE
        string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\zfam\My   Projects\programming\visual studio\XTrakker\XTrakker\runData.sdf";
        string mySelectQuery = "SELECT [int], [runDate], [runDist], [runTime], [runPace] FROM [runDataTable] order by [int] desc";
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["runDataTable"].NewRow();
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, myConnectionString);
        dr["runDate"] = date;
        dr["runDist"] = distData;
        dr["runTime"] = timeData;
        dr["runPace"] = milesDuration;

        ds.Tables["runDataTable"].Rows.Add(dr);

        SqlCeCommandBuilder projectBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataSet newSet = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
        adapter.Update(newSet, "runDataTable");
        adapter.Dispose();
```

Again, while I am in visual studio and I run the program, this all works as it should.  Once I publish, the listbox will only show the data from the current session, even the the actual database file is being updated.  Perhaps I am doing this all wrong?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but I am a bit confused about this line:

```
string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\zfam\My   Projects\programming\visual studio\XTrakker\XTrakker\runData.sdf";
```

Look like you hardcode your datasource provider. Are you sure you use the same datasource in visual studio, and when you publish your app?

Maybe the datasource is re-created at each execution, which could explain why you have always new data.